# Как изменить определенный бит в регистре

Tags: ассемблер

Долго шарил по интернету и так не понял как менять, например, 16-й бит в регистре rax (x64 бит) на 0

Answer (score 3):

"Изменить на 0" обычно называют "сбросить бит"

Для сброса конкретного бита, не трогая другие, нужно выполнить битовое AND с маской типа 11111011. А маску такую чтобы сделать - можно, например, выполнить сдвиг единицы влево, затем инвертировать (есть и другие способы, например, `rol -2, k`).

```
 mov rcx, 1   //00000001
 shl rcx, 2   //00000100
 not rcx      //11111011
 and rax, rcx   //xxxxx0xx
```

Установка бита производится с помощью OR

```
 mov rcx, 1
 shl rcx, 2
 or rax, rcx  //xxxxx1xx
```

А инверсия бита (изменение значения на противоположное) -  с помощью XOR

```
 mov rcx, 1
 shl rcx, 2
 xor rax, rcx   //xxxxx0xx =>xxxxx1xx, a xxxxx1xx => xxxxx0xx
```

Edit:
@Mike напомнил про инструкции BTR, BTS, BTC, непосредственно предназначенные для этих операций. Пример уже дан в ответе @t3f

Comment: Возможно ли использовать xor?
я так понимаю, что:
xor rax, 8000h
дает перевернутое значение 16-го бита. и если оно равно 1, то будет 0. Верно?

Comment: xor используется для изменения значения бита на противоположное (задача инверсии бита). Если нужный бит единичный, то станет нулевым, а вот если нулевой, то станет единичным. Но это ведь не то же самое, что безусловно сбросить в 0, верно?

Comment: UV, но дописали бы уж ещё как установить бит чтобы два раза не вставать: у топикстартера невнятно написано, что он хочет с битом сделать. Да и про инверсию перенести из комментов в ответ.

Comment: @A K Угу, хотел дождаться от автора уточнений на всякий случай

Comment: А еще я бы добавил, что в системе команд всей линейки intel, начиная с 80386 есть инструкции `bts` и `btr`, специально предназначенные для манипуляции битами

Answer (score 2):

В x86/x86_64 есть специальные инструкции для операций с отдельными битами:

```
btr rax, 16 ;сбросить (сделать равным 0) бит 16 в rax
bts rax, 16 ;установить (сделать равным 1) бит
btc rax, 16 ;инвертировать бит (противоположное значение)
```

Все эти инструкции также сохраняют предыдущее значение изменяемого бита, записывая его в CF (carry flag).

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, если вызывать функцию из C в masm, не может  ли флаг CF нарушить работу других функций?